# Check the paid app version through in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

My app has two versions **Free** and **Paid** in Google Play.

I want to add **inappbillingv3** to the free version and remove the paid version from Google Play.

If users install the free version and purchase the item to upgrade to the PRO version, then can I know If they have already installed the paid version?

Comment: Did you store if people upgrade pro version in server?

Comment: If people purchase item to upgrade then free versions all limitation will removed in free versions. But if people already have installed the paid version; upgrade dialog without display and remove all limitation in free version. I want to remove paid versions on googleplay and add the inappbilling the free versions (My purpose here is not their victims)

Comment: What's the different between that free versions all limitation will removed in free versions and upgrade dialog without display and remove all limitation in free version?

Comment: in free versions people cant see some categories and options. in paid versions people can see all categories and control the all options. I am very tired to deal with two applications so i want to remove paid version on googleplay and add the in appbilling to free version. When user purchase pro sku then all limitation will be remowed but if people already have paid versions upgrade will be free in purchase dialog.. so how i can control this?

Comment: You must has store if people has paid version in database on server.So check if people has paid version before show purchase dialog.Or can you tell me how do you store the purchase status.Maybe you can get purchase status form GoogleStore.

Comment: thank you for replies. I dont have a server so Might i can control purchase status from googlestore if user buy paid version..

Comment: I have never use google play.Maybe you can check google play document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if app is installed by using `PackageManager`'s [`getApplicationInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method

```
public abstract ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo (String packageName, int flags)
```

> Retrieve all of the information we know about a particular
>   package/application.
>
> Throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException if an application with the
>   given package name cannot be found on the system. Parameters
>   packageName   The full name (i.e. com.google.apps.contacts) of an
>   application. flags    Additional option flags. Use any combination of
>   GET_META_DATA, GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES, GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES to
>   modify the data returned. Returns
>
> ApplicationInfo Returns ApplicationInfo object containing information about the package. If flag GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES is set
>   and if the package is not found in the list of installed applications,
>   the application information is retrieved from the list of uninstalled
>   applications(which includes installed applications as well as
>   applications with data directory ie applications which had been
>   deleted with DONT_DELETE_DATA flag set).